# Are some recommendation questions considered as topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

There have be a few recommendation questions in the past. Some were in fact simply a resource request, which is considered on topic. Beer, Wine & Alcohol SE recommendation questions are quite common and on topic, but this is a different site altogether.

After reading this [recent question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84773/is-there-still-a-big-impact-of-st-john-of-the-cross-purging-of-the-soul-to-the) I thought it good to get some clear directives on this subject matter.

Comment: My quick thought is that any such questions should be quite tight, no more than half a dozen expected answers, and it shouldn't be about recommending things of personal preference or taste, but instead about making you aware of things that exist. That's why resource recommendations can work, but "your favourite English Bible translation" wouldn't. The linked question really doesn't belong - we don't recommend topics for research/study.

Comment: The linked question is basically an opinion polling question, so it's opinion-based, not really a resource request.  This is good meta question; we can start by trying to generate several examples of on-topic recommendation questions.